# using ajax to submit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My html code :

```
<?php echo form_open('question/submit', $attributes_form)

                <div style="margin-top:15px;" class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="post-question">提交问题</button>
                        <div id="#loading"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php echo form_close();?>
```

My query code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('#post-question').click(function()
    {
        alert('hello world');   
    });

    $('#question').submit(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url('question/submit');?>",
        type:post,
        beforeSend:function(event){
            $('#loading').html("<img src='<?php echo base_url('assets/img/loading.gif');?>'>");
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert("Success:" + data.result);
            $('#loading').empty();
        },
        error:function(data){
            $('#loading').empty();
            $('#loading').val("提交出错，请重试");
        },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click submit button, the page is redirected to question/submit, Why?
Since I'm using ajax post, I think the page should not be refreshed or redirected.

Answer (score 1):

You are not preventing the default action of the event, which is to submit the form (obviously):

```
$('#question').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: If I use this, does the form data will be posted to web server?

Comment: @Charles No, you should also post the form data yourself by setting `data` property of the `$.ajax` something like `data: $('form').serializeArray()`, also you should wrap the `post` with quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call .preventDefault() on the submit event.

```
$('#question').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        url:"<?php echo base_url('question/submit');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend:function(event){
            $('#loading').html("<img src='<?php echo base_url('assets/img/loading.gif');?>'>");
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert("Success:" + data.result);
            $('#loading').empty();
        },
        error:function(data){
            $('#loading').empty();
            $('#loading').val("提交出错，请重试");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems that this method prevent the form from posting to the web server?

Comment: see my edit. You need to grab the form data and send it in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

you're going to want to call the event.preventDefault() method to intercept the more typical html form / post submission since you're using this ajax approach